# Python recursion and scope of variable

Tags: python, recursion, reference

I'm trying to figure out the solution to this LeetCode problem [Palindrome Partitioning](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/). This is what I currently have:

```
def partition(s):
    out = []
    def isPalindrome(word):
        return word == word[::-1]

    def addPalindrome(word, start, partition):
        if start == len(word):
            out.append(partition)  #where I append to 'out'
            print out, partition  # where I print the finished partition
            return
        for i in range(start+1, len(word)+1):
            sub = word[start:i]
            if isPalindrome(sub):
                partition.append(sub)
                addPalindrome(word, i, partition)
                partition.pop()

    if not s:
        return []
    addPalindrome(s, 0, [])
    return out

print partition('aaa')
```

The correct solution to the input 'aaa' is `[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'aa'], ['aa', 'a'], ['aaa']]`. When I print `partition` in the base case it seems to be correct. I'm appending them to an `out` variable that should be out of scope of the recursion and return correctly.

However this is not the case. I do not understand why printing `out` in the base case would result in this:

```
[['a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'aa'], ['a', 'aa']]
[['aa', 'a'], ['aa', 'a'], ['aa', 'a']]
[['aaa'], ['aaa'], ['aaa'], ['aaa']]
```

Finally when returning `out`, it seems to return empty arrays. What's going on here?

The output of `out` after recursion is `[[], [], [], []]`.

This is Python2.7

Comment: You're using the same `partition` list again and again. You must create a new one everytime you want a new one, otherwise your result array just contains 4 references to the same `partition` list.

Comment: Here, if you wish to make it “fixed”, you must create a copy, like `out.append(list(partition))`

Answer (score 0):

The issues I see are 1) remembering to copy on save (as has been mentioned in the comments) and 2) the use of a global to save the growing result rather than handling that within the recursion.  Let simplify the code and fix both issues:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]

def addPalindrome(word, start, partitions):
    result = []

    if start == len(word):
        result.append(list(partitions))  # where I append to 'out'
    else:
        for i in range(start+1, len(word)+1):
            sub = word[start:i]

            if isPalindrome(sub):
                partitions.append(sub)
                result.extend(addPalindrome(word, i, partitions))
                partitions.pop()
    return result

def partition(s):
    out = []

    if s:
        out = addPalindrome(s, 0, [])

    return out

print partition('aaa')
```

When handing the result within the recursion, rather than as a global, the key is knowing when to `*.append()` and when to `*.extend()` the growing result.